# Problem with UISearchBar and NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, uisearchbar

I have a tableview with a search bar. I want to search my whole core data database.

I loaded everything into an array here:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; 
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
[request setEntity:entityDescription]; 
NSError *error = nil; 
NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];   
self.myArray = array;
```

I'm then searching using this method but getting an error:

```
- (void) searchTableView {

    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in myArray)
    {
        NSString *value = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
        [searchArray addObject:value];
    }

    for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
    }
    [searchArray release];
    searchArray = nil;
}
```

But when I search, I get the crash here:

```
MedicalCode *code = [self.copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
cell.codeLabel.text = code.description;
```

Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ICD9Disease objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1be6e0'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are asking for an object, but you're trying to set a string, in the line:

```
NSString *value = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Since you're getting a string, not an object, what you need to use is `valueForKey`:

```
    NSString *value = [dictionary valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that may have worked.  Based on that method, do you see why this line would be crashing? `MedicalCode *code = [self.copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.codeLabel.text = code.description;`

Comment: Are all of the objects in self.copyListOfItems of type MedicalCode? Also, is code.description a string? Finally, you may not need to call self on copyListOfItems. Can you post the crash in the console?

Comment: Yeah `description` is a string. Well if you look at the method above, copyListOfItems has objects added from self.myArray, which is the result of a NSFetchRequest of entity `MedicalCode`. This is crash `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString code]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f2070'
*** Call stack at first throw:`

Comment: Can you check what value you returned in numberOfRowsInSection and which array you used to measure the same? I believe you don't have that many in your copyListOfItems as you are conditionally collecting in it.

Comment: `cell.codeLabel.text` doesn't look right, are you sure that that isn't supposed to be `cell.textLabel.text`?

Comment: @Dylan, it is a custom cell subclass, codeLabel is just a UILabel.

Comment: @Saran, I have `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (searching)
        return [copyListOfItems count];
    else 
    {
        return 4;
    }
}`

Comment: @Faisal, hmmm... I'll keep thinking. Also, did I answer the question you initially asked in your post about objectForKey/valueForKey correctly? Not sure if it helped at all...

Comment: I'm not sure if it helped either.  Still got the same crash.  Remember, crash is happening at this line `MedicalCode *code = [self.copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.codeLabel.text = code.code;`

Comment: What are you talking about? A string is an object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting the fetch request to return dictionaries, but it's actually returning instances of the class ICD9Disease.